# Handling RequiredFieldValidator inside of a User Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a User Control which consists of a TextBox with a few extras, but for purposes of this example just assuming it's a plain TextBox will be sufficient. I am calling this User Control from a Web Form and would like to be able to use a RequiredFieldValidator that basically would function the same as if I used it on a TextBox on the web form. How do I configure my User Control to handle this?

**EDIT:**

DatePicker.ascx

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myControlTB">
```

DatePicker.ascx.cs

```
[ValidationProperty("Text")]
public partial class DatePicker : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public String Text { get { return myControlTB.Text; } set { myControlTB.Text = value; } }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

WebForm.aspx

```
<cu:UserControl runat="server" ID="myControl">
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" errormessage="This is a required field." ControlToValidate="myControl">
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

WebForm.aspx.cs

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate();
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        // e-mail the form
    }
```

Comment: this is similar to mine except I don't have a set on the property and my validator appears first.  Also, in my working code, I manually validate using Page.Validate() and check Page.IsValid.  It may not be too your requirements but may be worth checking if it works like this when calling the event or method that requires the validation to happen.

Comment: gave it a shot, but no luck :/ Thanks anyway.

Comment: hmmm, oddly enough if I put Page.Validate() in the Page_Load method this works. Unfortunately, this doesn't help for the client side validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to set the ValidationProperty attribute on the control and expose the Textbox Text property as a control property

```
 [ValidationProperty("Text")]
 public partial class Control
 {
    public string Text 
    {
        get { return textbox.Text;}
    }

 }
```

Comment: Don't want to sound needy, but could you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. I don't get an exception, but the requiredfieldvalidator doesn't correctly identify that the textbox is empty.

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while since I've done this.  Let me test it out and come back.  Did you try @Brian's first example?

Comment: It works ok for me, I did have the type name TextBox in my code and it should be myControlTB for you

Comment: No worries, thanks for your help. @Brian's first example did not work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to the user control:

```
public string TextBoxID
{
   get { return myControlTB.ClientID; }
}
```

And then for the validation control, programmably set it from code:

```
void Page_Load(..)
{
    this.rfv.ControlToValidate = this.uc.TextBoxID;
}
```

I actually don't know if it will work this way, but you could also try UniqueID, or the ID directly, and see if any of that makes a difference.

Either that, or change TextBoxID to TextboxText, and return myControlTB.Text, and add a [ValidationProperty("TextBoxText")] on the control, and set the ControlToValidate on the required field validator to the user control.

Try one of those approaches,

HTH.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Method 1 doesn't quite work. None of the ID properties (UniqueID, ClientID, ID) seem to get the correct ID. I get an exception saying that the RequiredFieldValidator can't find the control. Method 2 is the same that @Paul mentioned, but I haven't been able to get that working either.