# The RequiredFieldValidator for a drop down control inside of user control does not fire

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, requiredfieldvalidator

Following is the test scenario for my code.
1) Once the user selects one of the radio buttons on Webpage.aspx, a modal popup extender shows up. 
2) A user control  (SSL_Ticket.ascx) is defined inside the modal popup window. 
3) A RequiredFieldValidator is defined for a drop down list contained inside the user control. 
4) If the user selects the "0" value from drop down list, no validation error message is displayed.

## Code

Webpage.aspx

```
                     <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListForTicket" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true"
                         OnSelectedIndexChanged="radioButtonListForTicket_OnSelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">No</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
                      </asp:RadioButtonList>
                      <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtenderForTicket" runat="server" BackgroundCssClass="popUpStyle"
                          DropShadow="true" PopupControlID="divTicketPreview" PopupDragHandleControlID="panelDragHandle"
                          TargetControlID="btnForPopupAppear"   CancelControlID="btnForPopupDisappear"/>
```

....
                
                    
                        
                        
                        
                            
                         
                    
                
...

Webpage.aspx.cs

```
protected void radioButtonListForTicket_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonListForTicket.SelectedItem.Text.ToString().Equals("Yes"))
    {

        // Check if the sites are selected
        updateSelectionCount();
        updateListOfSites();

        if (selectionCount == 0)
        {
            lblSSLTicketSelection.Text = "Please select a site.";
            RadioButtonListForTicket.SelectedValue = "No";
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            lblSSLTicketSelection.Text = "";
        }

        ....

        ModalPopupExtenderForTicket.Show();
    }
}
```

...

SSL_Ticket.ascx

```
           <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbRootCause" runat="server" Width="255px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbRootCause_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"
                CausesValidation="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="0">Select</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Item1</asp:ListItem>
           </asp:DropDownList>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdFieldForRootCause" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cmbRootCause" InitialValue="Select" 
               ErrorMessage="Please select root cause" ValidationGroup="validateRootCause"  Visible="false" Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true">
           </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

...

SSL_Ticket.ascx.cs

```
    protected void cmbRootCause_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbRootCause.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Other"))
        {
            lblcmbRootCause.Text = "";
            lblcmbRootCause.Visible = false;
            txtRootCauseOther.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (cmbRootCause.SelectedItem.ToString().Equals("Select"))
        {
            lblcmbRootCause.Visible = true;
            lblcmbRootCause.Text = "Please select root cause";
        }
        else
        {
            lblcmbRootCause.Text = "";
            lblcmbRootCause.Visible = false;
            txtRootCauseOther.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

I did browse through couple of solutions (ValidateProperty, Client-side validation, RangeValidation, etc), but it did not fire validation text.

This did not help - [Handling RequiredFieldValidator inside of a User Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829758/handling-requiredfieldvalidator-inside-of-a-user-control)

I'd appreciate your help very much.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `visible = false` attribute from required field validator, by default they won't show up in the beginning.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqdFieldForRootCause" runat="server" ControlToValidate="cmbRootCause" InitialValue="Select" 
               ErrorMessage="Please select root cause" ValidationGroup="validateRootCause"  **Visible="false"** Display="Dynamic" EnableClientScript="true">
           </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. It shows the error message only if I select a valid root cause first and then select "Select" option from DDL. If I leave the root cause as "Select" (by default this is selected), no error message shows up. I am planning to implement the validation from javascript which will activate validation on Focus Change. Any pointers?

Comment: One more question please - I am not sure if the RequiredFieldValidator shown in code above is server-side validation or client-side validation. Please let me know.

Comment: They perform both client and server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

> Well in your 'RequiredFieldValidator' for your `DropDownList` you need to remove this:

```
InitialValue="Select"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But based on searching online solutions, they recommend adding the InitialValue to indicate the point when the validation should be fired i.e. at the time user selects the first/default item from DDL.

Comment: @user2136390 its not necessary. Its usually used to avoid valiadation for default values in a dropdownlist. For Ex: --Select-- Mark as answered if you found my inputs useful.

Comment: Thanks. After removing the "InitialValue" from the Validator, still no validation is triggered. If I select "Select" from the drop down list, it does not display error message "Please select a root cause". ANy pointers?